# Unable to integrate dracon flash captcha

Tags: php, ajax, flash, captcha

I tried to implement this captcha http://www.dracon.biz/captcha.php to a script

But It seems really hard i wasn't able to do it.

I tried to make a test php page but it wasn't successful either.

```
session_start();

# ~~~ CAPTCHA Form Submit ~~~~~~~~~~ # 
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'final') {
  if ($_SESSION['secCode_ok'] === true) {
    $_SESSION['secCode_ok'] = false;  // reset old results
```

then pass and execute query.

```
<input id="sec_code" class="input_captcha" maxlength="5" />
```

Can someone help me to get a working example file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only find these installation details from the forum => http://forum.dracon.biz/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=254&sid=ebb781531585ee16ab8574ba66ed3d14.
But I don't know that captcha solution. Why do you want to use this script. I don't like this solution because of:

- unnecessary flash dependency, most of the times flash downloads are bulky.
- bad documentation(no? Can't help you properly).

This solution are much easier if you ask me.

- http://www.easycaptchas.com/
- http://captchator.com/
- http://recaptcha.net/

because

- hosted.
- proper documentation.

Comment: I need that because of professional display and flash captcha is good against bots

Comment: okay I can't help you then, because I find docs lacking! Good luck